# Radio button value not "checked" in edit form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, radio-button

I have a table with the option edit on each row. When I click on edit, a form pops up and shows the fields filled out with the data to edit. However the selected radio button is not showing.
Can you tell what is missing in my code? Like how can I make the correct radio button show the checked value?

**Here is the edit form:**

```
<form action="edit_movie.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $movie['id']; ?>" /> <br>
Title:<br> <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $movie['title']; ?>" /> <br>
Release Year:<br> <input type="text" name="release_year" value="<?php echo $movie['release_year']; ?>" /> <br>
Director:<br> <input type="text" name="director" value="<?php echo $movie['director']; ?>" /> <br><br>
Select genre:
<br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="1"<?php if($movie['genre'] == 1) { echo ' checked'; } ?> />Action<br>
<br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="2"<?php if($movie['genre'] == 2) { echo ' checked'; } ?> />Comedy<br>
<br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="3"<?php if($movie['genre'] == 3) { echo ' checked'; } ?> />Drama<br>
<br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="4"<?php if($movie['genre'] == 4) { echo ' checked'; } ?> />Horror<br>
<br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="5"<?php if($movie['genre'] == 5) { echo ' checked'; } ?> />Romance<br>
<br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="6"<?php if($movie['genre'] == 6) { echo ' checked'; } ?> />Thriller<br>
<input type="submit" value="Update movie" />
</form>
```

**And here is the code for the edit:**

```
function get_movie_by_id($id){

   $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM movies m INNER JOIN categories c ON m.genre_id = c.genre_id WHERE id = '%s' LIMIT 1", mysql_real_escape_string($id));

   $result = mysql_query($query);

   if ( ! $result ){
       return false;
   } else {
         $return = array();

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

                $return = array('director' => $row['director'], 'genre' => $row['genre'], 'release_year' => $row['release_year'], 'title' => $row['title'], 'id' => $row['id']); 
         }
             return $return;
     }
}



if ( isset($_GET['edit']) ){

   $movie = get_movie_by_id($_GET['edit']);
}
```

Comment: What's in `$movie['genre']`?

Comment: Hi! It´s the same as genre_id. I have actually 2 tables one is for the genre and they have a foreign key relation between genre_id. But they are joined :  $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM movies m INNER JOIN categories c ON m.genre_id = c.genre_id WHERE id = '%s' LIMIT 1", mysql_real_escape_string($id));

Comment: I suspect `genre` and `genre_id` are not the same though... check it.

Comment: I tried to change it to genre_id as well. Everything else works like a charm. If I add a movie or update the movie or view the list of movies, genre is correct. It´s just that the value is not checked when i want to edit a existing film...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from your join that the field in question is "genre_id", not "genre":

```
$return = array('director' => $row['director'], 'genre' => $row['genre_id'], 'release_year' => $row['release_year'], 'title' => $row['title'], 'id' => $row['id']);
```

Comment: Omg, YES I see the issue and it worked like a charm by changing that to genre_id as well as the genre in the form to genre_id! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Another example of `SELECT *` being evil ;)